# hd issue on a laptop dell inspiron 1526 : if the issue was on the hd, would I be able to access/see the bios prompt?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, bios, dell-inspiron

I have an old laptop , a [dell inspiron 1526](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-1526/pd) which is not booting.

My first diagnostic would be to say the issue lies with the hd.

Yet when I'm powering the laptop, I cannot see the bios ...

My question: If the issue was with the hd, would I still be able to see/enter the bios after powering the laptop?

I'm asking the question because I'm uncertain that the issue lies with the hd...

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to enter the BIOS even with the HD removed ...

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill many thanks for your comment. aaarghh... I need to double check it.